# BouncyCastle .NET custom TlsClient for anon CipherSuite working on Android, but not Windows

Tags: c#, .net, bouncycastle

I've got access to a java application, which uses the CipherSuite `TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA` for communication (No possibility to use another one).

Some time ago I had to write a Xamarin App in C#, which connected to it successfully using Bouncy Castle PCL. I had to use Bouncy Castle, since Android (>=6.0) does not allow to use the previously mentioned cipher suite by default.

Now, I have to write a .NET application on Windows, which shall connect to the exact same Java application, so I just copied the code for establishing the connection and installed Bouncy Castle from NuGet. The TcpClient is able to establish a connection, but calling `protocol.Connect(new CustomTlsClient());` from the sample code below gives me the exception "System.IO.IOException: Internal TLS error, this could be an attack".

Overriding `NotifyAlertRaised` for the "CustomTlsClient" tells me, that Bouncy Castle fails to read a record (AlertLevel: 2, AlertDescription: 80, Message: "Failed to read record", Exception: "Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Tls.TlsFatalAlert: internal_error(80)").

Shortened sample Code:

```
...
TcpClient client = tryConnect(ip, port); // simply returns a TcpClient on success
NetworkStream targetStream = client.GetStream();
targetStream.ReadTimeout = Config.Network.TcpStreamReadTimeout;
targetStream.WriteTimeout = Config.Network.TcpStreamWriteTimeout;

TlsClientProtocol protocol = new TlsClientProtocol(targetStream, new Org.BouncyCastle.Security.SecureRandom()); 
protocol.Connect(new CustomTlsClient()); // <---- Here's the problem
...
```

CustomTlsClient:

```
private class CustomTlsClient : DefaultTlsClient
{
    public override TlsAuthentication GetAuthentication() => new CustomTlsAuthentication();
    public override int[] GetCipherSuites() => new[] { CipherSuite.TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA };

    public override void NotifyAlertRaised(byte alertLevel, byte alertDescription, string message, Exception cause)
    {
        // This gave me further information on the error
        base.NotifyAlertRaised(alertLevel, alertDescription, message, cause);
        Console.WriteLine("AlertLevel: " + alertLevel);
        Console.WriteLine("AlertDescription: " + alertDescription);
        Console.WriteLine("Message: " + message);
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + cause);
    }
}

private class CustomTlsAuthentication : TlsAuthentication
{
    public TlsCredentials GetClientCredentials(CertificateRequest certificateRequest) => null;
    public void NotifyServerCertificate(Certificate serverCertificate) { }
}
```

Since this code is working in a Xamarin App with the PCL version of Bouncy Castle, I really have no clue what I'm doing wrong here... Any suggestions? Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems to be a bug only appearing in the dedicated .NET NuGet package; uninstalling it and installing [Portable.BouncyCastle](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Portable.BouncyCastle/) instead solved the issue without changing a single line of code.